# Java/Spring - Difference in Stored Procedure call string

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, spring-batch

What is the difference between

```
private static final String STORED_PROC_CALL_STRING = "{? = call dbo.test1(?,?,?,?)}";
```

and

```
private static final String STORED_PROC_CALL_STRING = "{call dbo.test2(?,?,?,?)}";
```

More specifically: what is the meaning behind the `? =` at the beginning of the first statement, and how can I determine if the stored procedure I'm calling (on SQL Server) requires this or not?

Edit: I intend to create a `CallableStatement` and use the `.prepareCall()` method on it with the string supplied as a parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first syntax with the "?" mark in the beginning refers to a "[stored procedure with return status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378371.aspx)", that will be returned by procedure. This status is returned by procedure directly by using RETURN clause, you can check your procedure code and see it there.
The second one is just a call of your procedure with input (and possibly output) parameters.